# Filter collections Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to filter a collection returned by database query on Laravel?

Returned collection is this

```
 1 => Person {#310 ▼
      #table: "person"
      #attributes: array:15 [▼
        "name" => "Jon Doe"
        "timeavailable" => "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
 2 => Person {#310 ▼
      #table: "person"
      #attributes: array:15 [▼
        "name" => "Jon Moe"
        "timeavailable" => "1,2,5,7,8"
```

Here, I want to filter the `timeavailable` attribute. I only want to show results for `1,2,3` . Is there a way to filter this collection so that I only get something like this

```
1 => Person {#310 ▼
      #table: "person"
      #attributes: array:15 [▼
        "name" => "Jon Doe"
        "timeavailable" => "1,2,3"
 2 => Person {#310 ▼
      #table: "person"
      #attributes: array:15 [▼
        "name" => "Jon Moe"
        "timeavailable" => "1,2"
```

So, the filtered collection will have only `1,2,3` inclusions.

Comment: One way is to use `FIND_IN_SET` mysql function in your query. Second is to use a callback to filter function where you explode `timeavailable` and see if items in it fits your condition. And third way is to improve your database design, so `Person` will have __many__ `TimeAvailable`.

Comment: Do you want to remove `Person` instances from your collection where they don't have 1, 2 and 3 in their `timeavailable` field? In this example `John Moe` would be removed (Has 1 and 2, but doesn't have 3) and `John Doe` would still be present (Has 1, 2 and 3). Or are you trying to achieve something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not the best solution, but it can be a way to solve for this problem. Check if this helps...

Try to use the `map` of `Collection`. In the inner function, you can explode, intersect and explode `timeavailable`.

```
$limiter = [1,2,3];
$filtered = $array->map(function($person, $k) use ($limiter) {
    $ex = explode(',', $person->timeavailable);
    $intersect = array_intersect($limiter, $ex);
    $person->timeavailable = implode(",",$intersect);
    return $person;
});
```

This will work fine for small results, but if you are planning to run this with lots of results, it will be slow.